# Javascript click function not working in Chrome devtools on a pop-up on the youtube website that adds videos to a playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a script in js to reverse copy a playlist from someone and reverse its order. The last part of it is Adding those links to my own created playlist where I find the buttons that I would have to click, map them to an object and run the click() on them.
This was working for:

1. Clicking of the 3 dots to open options

[image] and

2. Clicking the add videos button

[image]. 
 
Problems arise on the opening of the ["add videos to a playlist"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgozY.png) pop-up box. The click() doesn't work on any button here. Or any element inside the button. I want to click on the url tab here and then a link that I have and then press the 'add button' video. I'm looking to regain the functionality of click() or do it with a simpler method.

The selector for the url button is document.querySelector("#\:6") upon running the click function on which yeilds `VM5 common.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')  at Object.sendMessage (VM5 common.js:4:101)  <at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (content.js:109:448)`

I have found that forcing the hover state doesn't do anything either so maybe it has something to do with responding to a real mouse rather than js functions. Another guess is that the pop-up might have introduced a wall in front of the whole screen which is blocking the click function from working. I don't understand how I could've troubleshooted this by setting breakpoints as I don't know where to start.

[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.